# How to parse and validate Domain & Subdomain roots in C#

Tags: c#, regex, url, dns, subdomain

Though I've been looking through some of the classes I've been having a hard time finding an efficient way to parse/regex domains (both root and subdomains, while including things like .co.uk, etc).

Is there a function that can validate whether or not it is a proper domain/url without actually connecting to the site? My goal is to use this for a large list of URL's to grab pretty much anything before (and including) the TLD.

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/189878/regex-to-validate-the-index-of-a-website-vs-a-specific-page

Comment: There's no way to determine TLDs, apart from having a big list of all of them - Mozilla maintains one as the Public Suffix List: http://publicsuffix.org/

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to tweak the regex for your particular situation, but this gives you a point where to start:

```
const string pattern = @"http[s]?://(?<Domain>([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+?\.)*([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)*([a-zA-Z]{3,61}|[a-zA-Z]{1,}\.[a-zA-Z]{2,3}))"; //";
var regex = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
var match = regex.Match(myURL);
var domain = match.Groups["Domain"].Value;
```